# Como remover linhas TableView mesmo com campo de pesquisa utilizando JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, table, algoritmo-de-busca

Eae pessoal,
Estou tentando colocar a opção de limpar TableView no meu projeto, porém como tenho implementado a opção de pesquisa sempre que tento limpar a TableView é apresentado este erro: ***Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.***
Se comento meu método responsável pela pesquisa a opção de limpar TableView funciona perfeitamente.
Se possivel poderia por gentileza compartilhar algum exemplo de TableView com **pesquisa** e opção de **delete**, já vasculhei no google mas não encontrei nenhum exemplo com as duas opções funcionando.

Método de pesquisa que estou utilizando:

```
public void pesquisaTableView(ObservableList<Dados> table, TextField filterField, TableView<Dados> tablev) {

    // Wrap the ObservableList in a FilteredList (initially display all data).
    FilteredList filteredData =  new FilteredList<>(table, b -> true);

    // 2. Set the filter Predicate whenever the filter changes.
    filterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredData.setPredicate(employee -> {
            // If filter text is empty, display all persons.

            if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
                if (employee.getSituacao() != null) 
                {
                    if (employee.getSituacao().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter) == true) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

            return false; // Does not match.
        });
    });

    // 3. Wrap the FilteredList in a SortedList.
    SortedList<Dados> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);

    // 4. Bind the SortedList comparator to the TableView comparator.
    //    Otherwise, sorting the TableView would have no effect.
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(tablev.comparatorProperty());

    // 5. Add sorted (and filtered) data to the table.
    tablev.setItems(sortedData);

}
```

Erro completo:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
```

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título. Sei que é comum em muitos fóruns, mas aqui funciona diferente. Você já marcou uma resposta como aceita (quando clicou no ✓) e isso já é o suficiente para indicar que foi resolvido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver colocando todos os dados dentro de um ObservableList global e limpei as linhas do obsList com o metodo clear(). Abaixo trecho do código utilizado:

```
    private ObservableList<DadosXml> obsListTableDados = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


// Metodo resposavel por filtrar por colunas a pesquisa
    public void pesquisaTableView(ObservableList<Dados> obsListDadosXml, TextField filterField, TableView<Dados> tablev) {

        // Wrap the ObservableList in a FilteredList (initially display all data).
        FilteredList<Dados> filteredData =  new FilteredList<>(obsListTableDados, b -> true);

        // 2. Set the filter Predicate whenever the filter changes.
        filterField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            filteredData.setPredicate(employee -> {
                // If filter text is empty, display all persons.

                if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                } 
                else {
                    String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
//                                    System.out.println("lowerCaseFilter "+lowerCaseFilter);
//                                    System.out.println(employee.getSituacao());
                    if (employee.getSituacao() != null) {
                        if (employee.getSituacao().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter) == true) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }                    
                }// fim else
                return false; // Does not match.
            });
        });

        // 3. Wrap the FilteredList in a SortedList.
        SortedList sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);

        // 4. Bind the SortedList comparator to the TableView comparator.
        //    Otherwise, sorting the TableView would have no effect.
        sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(tablev.comparatorProperty());

        // 5. Add sorted (and filtered) data to the table.
        tablev.setItems(sortedData);

    }


    // Metodo para limpar linhas TableView
    public  void limpaDados()
    {
obsListTableDados.removeAll(table.getItems());
}
```